# CTRL + C doesn't kill C script

Tags: c, bash, kill

I'm reading [Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces](https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eremzi/OSTEP/) and I'm finding a problem is not mentioned in the book.

This is the C script:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
/*#include "common.h"*/
#include <unistd.h>
#include <assert.h>


int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int *p = malloc(sizeof(int));
    assert(p != NULL);
    printf("(%d address pointed to by p: %p\n",
            getpid(), p);
            *p = 0;
            while (1) {
                sleep(1);
                *p = *p +1;
                printf("(%d) p: %d\n", getpid(), *p);
            }
            return 0;
}
```

It allocates some memory, prints out the address memory, puts the number 0 into it and finally loops to increment the value.

I compile it through `gcc -o mem mem.c -Wall` and I have no problem running it with `./mem`, if I press CRTL+C it will stop:

[image]

But then problems come when I run the script twice in parallel with the command `./mem & ./mem`, look at the GIF:

[image]

No matter how many times I try to kill the process the scripts keeps hammering.

How to kill my C which project?

Comment: Aside, as `getpid()` may return something wider than `int`, consider a cast: `printf("%d\n", (int) getpid());` to get that potential UB out of the way of demo'ing this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `fg` to bring the backgrounded process to the foreground, then it will respond to <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>.

You can also use `jobs` to see a numbered list of backgrounded jobs, and `kill %<number>` to kill a specific job, e.g. `kill %1`.

Comment: How can I write fg while the terminal is taken by this process?

Comment: Pretend it's not there. The shell will still take your input.

Comment: Thank you @John, it worked `fg` and then CTRL+C

Comment: But why is going on background by default?

Comment: Commands can be terminated by `;` or `&`. The default is `;` (which is optional): `cmd` and `cmd ;` will run a command in the foreground. `cmd &` will run it in the background. When you wrote `./mem & ./mem` it was like typing `./mem & ./mem ;` -- the first one runs in the background, the second in the foreground.